# C++ Creating Dynamic 2D Array With One Statement but Without auto

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, new-operator

I've seen that a dynamic 2D array in `C++` can be created as follows:

```
auto arr{ new int[nRows][nCols] };
```

`nRows` and `nCols` are compile-time known and the size of the array will not change during runtime.

I've tested what is the type of `arr` is `PAx_i` (where `x` is `nCols`). But I cannot figure out what to put instead of `auto` (if I don't want to use it) to create a dynamic 2D array with a single statement.

So, the question: Is it possible in `C++` to specify the type of a dynamic 2D array directly (`C`-style like)? If yes, how?

Comment: Assuming `nCols` is compile-time known (otherwise the code itself is bogus from inception), `int (*arr)[nCols] { new int[nRows][nCols] };` should work.

Comment: @WhozCraig, `nRows` and `nCols` are compile-time known (will update the question now). Compiler throws me a bunch of errors. One of them is `‘arr’ was not declared in this scope`. Thus, it looks like more than one line of code is required.

Comment: "Compiler throws a bunch of errors" - No, it doesn't: [See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/q3zfsh7n4). The **exact** line I proposed does *exactly* what you asked.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you're right. I don't remember what my code was when I tried to test your proposal.

Comment: @WhozCraig That would declare `arr` as pointer to array nCols of int. The 2D array is a single block  of memory, not an array of pointers.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  The line I posted crafts a *single* block allocation. to populate a array-nRows of array-nCols of `int`; e.g. a genuine 2D array (an array of arrays). There is no "array of pointers" in that code whatsoever. So I don't know what you're talking about, and/or I'm not sure you understood the question, my proposal, and possibly both.

Comment: @WhozCraig I think my point is that your type is highly confusing. Also that you loose the size (rows) of the matrix because you decay it to a pointer to columns. You are right though that there is no array of pointers, my mistake. It kind of hurts my eyes that you would have to define different types for a Matrix and pointer to Matrix: `using Matrix = int[nrows][ncols]; using Matrix_ptr = int(*)[ncols];` I would always wrap the whole thing in a `struct` so you could use `Matrix *` as a type.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That is definitely a fundamental difference. Hiding pointer types in typedef/using aliases is nearly always considered code-smell for C or C++ developers. The structural burial, however, has long had merit, and is akin to the foundations of what eventually became OOP. Note that I never said this is what I would do. And note: that isn't "my" type. It is **the** resultant type of the `new` expression pondered by the OP, and is inarguable. That said, I would never do this in C++ without having a *very* good reason behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ does not support dynamically-sized *raw* arrays (aka Variable Length Arrays, or VLAs). Whenever you come across the need for such a dynamic array (how ever many dimensions it may have), you should be immediately thinking of using the [`std::vector` container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Once properly created, you can use the `[]` operator (concatenated, for 2-D vectors) in much the same way as you would with raw arrays.

Here's a short code demo that creates a dynamic, 2-dimensional 'array' of integers, using the `std::vector` class, and initializes all elements with an especially significant, non-zero value:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    size_t nCols, nRows;
    std::cout << "Enter nRows and nCols: ";
    std::cin >> nRows >> nCols;
    if (nCols < 2 || nRows < 2) {
        std::cout << "Matrix is too small!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // The following SINGLE LINE declares and initializes the matrix...
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(nRows, std::vector<int>(nCols, 42));
    std::cout << "nRows = " << arr.size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "nCols = " << arr[0].size() << "\n";
    for (auto& row : arr) {
        for (auto i : row) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    // Demo for how to use the "[][]" operator ...
    arr[0][0] = arr[nRows - 1][nCols - 1] = 33; // Change 1st and last
    std::cout << "------------\n";
    for (auto& row : arr) {
        for (auto i : row) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One of the great benefits of using `std::vector` over `new[]` is that you don't have to worry about subsequently calling `delete[]` – the container class takes care of all memory allocation and deallocation internally.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! `nRows` and `nCols` are compile-time known and the array is of static size (I've updated the question description). I thought about `std::vector` but was just curious about using `C`-style arrays.

Comment: @ENIAC  If the sizes are compile-time constants, then what's wrong with a simple array declaration, such as `int arr[nRows][nCols];` ?

Comment: If I understand it right, without `new`, the array is located on the stack.

Comment: @ENIAC Yes, that's probably right. But *with* the `new` it can never be a "C-style array".

Comment: You're right. Thank you for pointing that out! I think I'll use `std::vector` in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ try to avoid new/delete unless you have no other choice.
Next up is std::make_unique (or std::make_shared).
For dynamic arrays C++ has 'std::vector'

Like this :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // 2x2 vector
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> values{ {0,1},{2,3},{4,5} };
    std::cout << values[1][1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought about `std::vector` but was just curious about using `C`-style arrays.

Comment: "C" style arrays are hardly ever needed anymore, if I need fixed size arrays I use std::array much less painful to move around (you can use it like any other class). "C" Style arrays are still mostly used since most people learned that in (datatstructures) class. The STL containers do most of the heavy work and allow you to write code with less bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Thusly, vector of vector, in this case the values are uninitialized.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr(nRows,std::vector<int>(nCols));
```

You can also do this with gcc compiler, but its not per standard, and won't work if nRows or nCols is variable in Visual Studio:

```
int arr[nRows][nCols];
```

It's better for you to get comfortable with C++ standard library, as it will open up new worlds for you.

Another way:

```
int *arr = new int[nRow*nCol];
```

You can then index into the flat buffer like:
arr[0][1]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought about `std::vector` but was just curious about using `C`-style arrays.